# How to make sure I am and stay connected to a particular WiFi access point (if it's available)?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, router

I'm frequently working from within a campus network, which I connect to through WiFi (Win10). Unfortunately, due to my somewhat inconvenient location, the speed of my internet access varies considerably depending on which access point I am connected to. At some point, I figured out that I can manually change the access point I connect to using [NetSetMan](https://www.netsetman.com/en/freeware) (free version). So this is what I've been doing ever since: Whenever I notice that my connection gets worse, I open the WiFi manager, search for "my" access point in the list (as identified by its MAC address) and click 'Connect'. Once I've made the choice, it's usually good for a few hours until Windows/NetSetMan - don't know - decides I should better use some other access point. And so the whole process starts again.

This is obviously not very convenient. Ideally, I would like to make Windows or some software to always try this particular access point first when connecting to the network. If it is within reach, I want to be (and stay) connected to it; if not, Windows should just do what it normally does.

Do you know of a (preferably: free and lightweight) way to achieve that?

Comment: Windows 10 Wireless Connections are automatic if strength is adequate (1 to 1.5 bars of 5) . Otherwise you need to change it manually. I think built-in Windows 10 is probably as good as any like application. I move my laptop around consulting and depend on the Windows 10 app.

Comment: @John, well, the problem is simply that Windows, by default, almost always connects me to one of the 'bad' access points. (It might have better signal strength, I don't know, all I know is that the other one is way faster.) Therefore, being able to manually change access points was a big improvement for me. It would be even better if I didn't have to do this manually.

Comment: I keep only my important access points. I use NETSH WLAN DELETE profile name={profile name} to get rid of lesser used or bad access points and do not connect to them